# How does a Webpack isomorphic/universal plugin work?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've found 2 tools for solving the issue with module loaders on server side: [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-react-redux-isomorphic-render-example) and [universal-webpack](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/universal-webpack). Can someone please explain me the crucial steps how these things work? How does it capture/extract the `import`ed / `require`d modules?

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of these 3 modules.

`webpack-isomorphic-tools` hooks into Node.js's `require()` function with the help of `require-hacker` and intercepts `require()` calls for all assets with configured `extension`s returning their Webpack-compiled form (taken from `webpack-assets.json` generated by `webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin` during Webpack build).

`universal-webpack` doesn't hook into `require()` function - it's just a helper for transforming client-side Webpack configuration to a server-side Webpack configuration. It doesn't run on the server-side or something. It's just a Webpack configuration generator - turned out that Webpack has a `target: "node"` parameter which makes it output code that runs on Node.js without any issues.

I wrote `webpack-isomorphic-tools` before `universal-webpack`, so `universal-webpack` is the recommended tool.
However many people still use `webpack-isomorphic-tools` (including me) and find it somewhat less complicated.

Comment: "and does what needs to be done" hardly answers the question of "how it works".

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. Reverted my downvote. An upvote for the follow up.